# Does flutter local notifications have an onShown callback?

Tags: localnotification

It would be really nice to have a callback that would be called when notification is shown.

I couldn't find any way to listen to the onShown event in Flutter local notification. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question? Currently I am trying to implement this to play a custom sound that was recorded during runtime when a notification was shown.